# WPF Listview Checkboxcolumn Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I'm having trouble binding a Checkboxcolumn to a Listview. What am I doing wrong? XAML-Code:

```
<ListView Name="listViewClients" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,10" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Auswahl" Width="50">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Anrede" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding salutation}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Titel" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding title}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Vorname" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding first_name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Nachname" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding last_name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="UnitNr" Width="105" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding commercialunitnumber}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

C#-Code:

```
listViewClients.Items.Clear();

for (int a = 0; a < clients.Count; a++)
{
    listViewClients.Items.Add(new
    {
        isChecked = false,
        salutation = clients[a].salutation,
        title = clients[a].title,
        first_name = clients[a].first_name,
        last_name = clients[a].last_name,
        commercialunitnumber = clients[a].commercialunitnumber,
    });
}
```

This works fine for all the other Columns, but throws an error when trying to bind the IsChecked property. Why? The Error I get is in German, but here´s the ~ translation:

XamlParseException: TwoWay- or OneWayToSource-Connections don't work with the write-protected property "isChecked".

**EDIT:**

Ok, I´ve found the error now. I created a class named Clients, here´s the C#-code:

```
class Clients
{
    public Boolean isChecked { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("salutation")]
    public string salutation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("commercialunitnumber")]
    public string commercialunitnumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then I just changed the C#-Code thats filling the ListView to:

```
listViewClients.Items.Clear();

for (int a = 0; a < clients.Count; a++)
{
    listViewClients.Items.Add(new Clients
    {
        isChecked = false,
        salutation = clients[a].salutation,
        title = clients[a].title,
        first_name = clients[a].first_name,
        last_name = clients[a].last_name,
        commercialunitnumber = clients[a].commercialunitnumber,
    });
}
```

The only thing I changed is listViewClients.Items.Add(new **Clients** {...});

Comment: Anonymous type will create read-only properties and `CheckBox` by default binds `TwoWay` and that's not allowed. Create proper view model class with writeable properites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Create your proper view model class with writable properties because as mentioned "Anonymous type will create read-only properties".

i added here an example of Clients View model implements `INotifyProprtychanged` (i didn't add all the property)

```
 // This is a simple Clients class that  
    // implements the IPropertyChange interface. 
    public class Clients: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // These fields hold the values for the public properties. 
        private bool isChecked = false;
        private string title = String.Empty;
        private string first_name = String.Empty;
        private string last_name = String.Empty;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        // The constructor is private to enforce the factory pattern. 
        private Clients()
        {

        }

        // This is the public factory method. 
        public static Clients CreateNewCustomer()
        {
            return new Clients();
        }

        // This property represents an ID, suitable 
        // for use as a primary key in a database. 
        public bool IsChecked 
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isChecked;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.isChecked)
                {
                    this.isChecked = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return this.title;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.title)
                {
                    this.title = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.first_name;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.first_name)
                {
                    this.first_name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.last_name;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.last_name)
                {
                    this.last_name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you just need to use it at your list creation:

```
listViewClients.Items.Clear();

for (int a = 0; a < clients.Count; a++)
{
    listViewClients.Items.Add(new Clients
    {
        isChecked = false,
        salutation = clients[a].salutation,
        title = clients[a].title,
        first_name = clients[a].first_name,
        last_name = clients[a].last_name,
        commercialunitnumber = clients[a].commercialunitnumber,
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-) I´ve already found the solution (see the edit of my post), but I will have a look at implementing the INotifyProprtychanged...